# Post Request is not returning same object as passed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to do a simple CRUD app asp.net core using MVC and the strangest thing is happening to me.

create the model and pass it in to the form but when I go to save it, it no longer has the Id that I passed into it.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateCompany(Guid id)
    {
        //id = 677b57f1-d0b2-484b-9892-b06e6eb9f1f7
        var pageId = id;
        var company = new CompanyListItem() {PublicPageId = pageId};
        return View(company);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateCompany(CompanyListItem model)
    {
         //model.PublicPageId = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            var newModel = _companyDataProvider.Add(model);
            PublicPageViewModel page = null;
            if (newModel != null)
            {
                page = _pageDataProvider.GetPageIdFromCompanyListId(newModel.Id);
            }
            if (page != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Details", page);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

my form:

```
@model CompanyListItem

<h1>Add Company</h1>
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Header"></label>
            <input asp-for="Header" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save"/>
            <a class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or how i can prevent it from happening?

Comment: You do not generate any form control for property `PublicPageId` so its value cannot be sent back. Include a hidden input for it in the form.

Comment: can you please send an example? I have tried @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.PublicPageId) and it is still doing it

Comment: thank you that did it, i chagned from @html to input thanks agan